# Shared contact list in Exchange/Outlook?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, outlook

I want to create a mailing list of our internals staff, external email addresses.  This is to update them on company news.  This is to be only shared between 5 staff members.  What's the best way to achieve this?

We use exchange 2007 and outlook email clients.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve this is to use your employee's internal email addresses, and not have to worry about things like deliverability, being blocked by employees who don't want to bothered with company news on personal time or the legality of using that information for this purpose.

Personally, I'd send any emails like you're describing directly to the spam folder and start floating my resume to recruiters if a company I worked for started doing this.

Comment: We are a manufacturing company so most of the employees dont have user accounts/computers at work. We need a way to comunicate with them.  We ask the employees to give us their email addresses so we can communicate what we are trying to do with the company. e.g. new customers, general news ect.. Its totally up to them if they give us an address.

Comment: @resolver101  If you truly need to communicate with them, then you truly need to set up a corporate communication system that they have access to, simple as that.  I set up a hosted Exchange system for a similar company a while back for ~$5/user/month, with no administration overhead, short of adding or removing users.  Might be something worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be referring to isn't really "shared contacts" but rather a way to email employee's external "personal" email addresses, correct?  Why you wouldn't send company news to their company email accounts is beyond me, but...

If you really want to go down that road:

1. Create contacts for them in Exchange.  Say "Bob Smith - Personal", with SMTP address of "bobsmithpersonal@gmail.com" or similar.
2. These email contacts by default will show up in the GAL, so people can use them internally to email individual "contacts" as required/needed
3. You can also create a distribution list at this point in Exchange, maybe "All Personal Email Contacts" and add the contacts you created in #1 above to this distro list.  The distro list will also show up in the GAL and you can have users email it and it will send the email to all the contacts in that list.

Comment: We are a manufacturing company so most of the employees don't have user accounts/computers at work. We need a way to communicate with them.  In answer to your question: Yes we want to communicate with employees via their personal emails.  i cant see a way to give only certain people access to the distribution list.  am i missing something?

Comment: You can set the "accept messages from" in the distro list properties in the EMC, under mail flow settings, message delivery restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:

-On one of the Outlook PC's I've created a contact list.   Shared the
-contact list with the appropriate people.
-On the client list, I filtered the list to only show emails and chose only to show the email field.
-I can now copy and paste the list into outlook mail "TO" and emailed to the relevant people.